# No packages info while installing using yum -y install

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, rhel6

I am trying to migrate an application from onprem to cloud, wherein while deploying it in AWS we found that many packages were not installed with ami deployment so we used the following command to install the packages which shows the below info but those packages are there when I checked in on-prem servers.

```
/usr/bin/rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
/usr/bin/yum install -y php-devel php-pecl-memcached --enablerepo=remi-php54
/usr/bin/yum -y --enablerepo=remi install php-pecl-msgpack php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-igbinary php-pecl-apcu  php-mcrypt php-common php-cli php-mysql php-process
```

No process php-process available

tried enabling remi

Comment: EL-6 repository are closed, distro is no more maintained.
But AFAIK, amz2 image is based on EL-7

Comment: See https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/: `Enterprise Linux 6 has reached its "End Of Life" in November 2020.`